# Combine just one element for each array, without repetition and considering all possible combinations

Tags: php

I'm having serious difficulties to solve this problem. Thank you in advance for any help.

---

The query request of availability of hotel rooms looks as follows:

[image]

Where 'groups_rooms' is an array collection with variuos rooms for each key, you need to take just one room for each group_room to complete all the required availability.

For example, to this case the following are the expected result:

```
$result = array (
   array(room1, room4, room5),
   array(room1, room4, room6),
   array(room2, room4, room5),
   array(room2, room4, room6),
   array(room3, room4, room5),
   array(room3, room4, room6),
   //...
);
```

To explain a little more this question, I show the exact appearance of a response of a request availability:

Query: 5 adults and 3 children.

[image]

"paxes", it is the combination of adults and children in string format separated by a hyphen:

```
$adults .'-'. $children;
```

in the above result you can be seen paxes the following:

- '1-2': Rooms to 1 adult and 2 children
- '2-0': Rooms to 2 adults and 0 children
- '2-1': Rooms to 2 adults and 1 children

If you take only one room per pax, you get the total availability that you need for 5 adults and 3 children.

the expected result:

```
$result = array (
   array(room1, room4, room5), // option one to 5 adults and 3 children
   array(room1, room4, room6), // option two to 5 adults and 3 children
   array(room2, room4, room5), // option three to 5 adults and 3 children
   array(room2, room4, room6), // etc.
   array(room3, room4, room5),
   array(room3, room4, room6),
   //...
);
```

Tank you!

---

### EDIT

The following link contains the solution to this problem, using brute force, but Im looking for a more elegant solution.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/be38e9e97cf4ad3937eb0c9af807f45f0f5de66c

Thanks.

Comment: How are you storing your data? This seems like something mysql could do nicely.

Comment: The diagram of the image corresponds to the json response from an API. 
That information is not stored in the database. thank you.

Comment: so you acutally have keys like "2-1" or do you have "group3" as your key; if so, do you have a separate array linking group3 to "2-1" ?

Comment: No, the keys can complete any name but the name is always the "adults-children", for example, a response json real is this:  {"availability":{"2-0":[["room 1 information"],["room 2 information"]],"2-1":[["room 3 information"]],"1-0":[["room 4 information"],["room 5 information"],["room 6 information"]]}}, that was the availability to 5 adults and 1 children. Its works if you take only one room per "pax"

Comment: So, if you don't have it in a query-able form, I'd imagine you'd simply write something to iterate over all the possible combinations of rooms, and save them to an array if they match your criteria?

Comment: This is a solution to my problem but is resolved by brute force: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5004f01874b79b51161d6dfa3fbf5b4ddd14d72e  but im looking for a more elegant and  short solution, for example using recursive functions.